# Why does the my select form not send the variable in the value parameter?

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I am making a page that sends data in the POST and refreshes when you click on a select list option. The data is retrieved from a database.  I am using the this.form.submit() function to send the variable when you click on an option. However, for some reason, it doesn't send the variable in the value="" of the option box but the text in between the ><. Below is the piece of code I thought was relevant:

```
    echo '<form method="post">';
            echo "<select onchange='this.form.submit()' id='chose_category' name = 'chose_category'>";

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($hoofdrubrieken)){
            echo '<option "value="' . $row['number'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>'; 
    echo'</form>';
```

In this case, the variable in $row['name'] is send as a POST variable, instead of $row['number']. I have checked this by printing the POST variable. Is there any way to send $row['number'] here, but still displaying $row['name']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($hoofdrubrieken)){
            echo '<option "value="' . $row['number'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
```

To:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($hoofdrubrieken)){
            echo '<option  value="' . $row['number'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
```

Your current produces something like :

```
<select onchange='this.form.submit()' id='chose_category' name = 'chose_category'>
<option "value="number">name</option>
</select>
```

You need to remove the double-quote.

Comment: That was a really easy solution, I don't understand why I don't see things like that. Thank you a lot!